# how to remove all <a to /a> tag in c# using regex.replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex, tags

i want the output with regex.replace :

input :

```
<h4 class=\"nikstyle_title\"><a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href="http://www.sample.com">my text</a></h4>
```

output :

```
<h4 class=\"nikstyle_title\"> </h4>
```

Comment: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: Never use regex for parsing html. There is html parser !

Comment: [Please don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11683). Use a parser.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you !

Comment: @user20982 see https://regex101.com/r/rZ2uV3/3

Comment: tnx Avinash Raj . resolved .  the true answer is : ()<a.*?>.*?<\/a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use regex to parse html, you need html parser. Here is an example how you can do it.

You need to add this reference in your project:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

**The code:**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A!!</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>2!!</td>
        <td>te43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> !!</td>
        <td>.!!</td>
        <td>te53</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>texx</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h4 class=""nikstyle_title""><a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.niksalehi.com/ccount/click.php?ref=ZDNkM0xuQmxjbk5wWVc1MkxtTnZiUT09&id=117""><span class=""text-matn-title-bold-black"">my text</span></a></h4>

</body>
</html>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            List<HtmlNode> tdNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "h4" && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("nikstyle_title")).ToList();


            foreach (HtmlNode node in tdNodes)
            {
                node.InnerHtml = "";
            }

            string html2 = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

For your second desire -> Remove every `<a></a>` tag with `href="http://www.sample.com":

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A!!</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>2!!</td>
        <td>te43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> !!</td>
        <td>.!!</td>
        <td>te53</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>texx</td>

    </tr>
</table>

<h4 class=""nikstyle_title""><a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.sample.com""><span class=""text-matn-title-bold-black"">my text</span></a></h4>
<div><a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.sample.com""><span class=""text-matn-title-bold-black"">my text</span></a></div>
</body>
</html>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            List<HtmlNode> tdNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes.Contains("href") && x.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("http://www.sample.com")).ToList();

            foreach (HtmlNode node in tdNodes)
            {

                node.Remove();
            }

            string html2 = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
```

Also personally I prefer to use `@` for escaping because it is more readable, you can try like in my example. When you are using `@` you will escape with double quotes-example: `class=""a"";`

Comment: please read my question again. not just h4 tag, another tag , so i dont know the tag. i want to remove anythings between <a anythins /a>

Comment: Why your document have [, change it to < ...

Comment: please read my question again. not just h4 tag, another tag , so i dont know the tag. i want to remove anythings between <a anythins /a>

Comment: Write your question better at the moment, my code is doing your desire.

Comment: i want to remove any link with it's <a tag and it's text or any other thing in between <a tag in a page. your code is good but do this?

Comment: @user20982 Here check my EDIT, with full example !

Comment: tnx mybirthname for your answer. my problem was solved.  List<HtmlNode> tdNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes.Contains("href")).ToList();

Comment: @user20982 you are welcome, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack is not so universal. Sometimes only regex can save your time. In C# you can use this code:

```
string htmlString = "";
        var regex = new Regex("<h4 class=\\\"nikstyle_title\\\">(?<delete>.*?)<\\/h4>");
        string replace = regex.Match(htmlString).Groups["delete"].Value;
        htmlString = htmlString.Replace(replace, string.Empty);
```

Your regex is:

```
<h4 class=\"nikstyle_title\">(?<delete>.*?)<\/h4>
```

Comment: you should never use regex ! Also please tell me in which case HtmlAgilityPack will not save you ? The save is pretty easy in this case.

Comment: Some websites made wrong. For exmple: <tag>bla bla bla</tag> some text without tag, but i need it <tag/>....

Comment: please read my question again. not just h4 tag, another tag , so i dont know the tag. i want to remove anythings between <a anythins /a>

Comment: When the html is invalid you should fix the html not the method with which you are going to read it !

Comment: Hehe, this should work if you are parsing your website. But what if i want to parse yahoo news for example?